# Java two classes I need assistance with main method

Tags: java

in the main method what do I write in order to create a new bilagare

the format needs to be (String, String, personbil)

bilagare a = new bilagare (name, adress, AND WHAT DO I WRITE HERE TO GIVE the object one of the cars created );

```
public class bilagare 
{
        Personbil personbil;

        private String namn;
        private String adress;

    // konstruktor
        public bilagare (Personbil personbil, String namn, String adress)
            {
             this.personbil=personbil;
             this.namn= namn;
             this.adress = adress;

            }
    // returnerar namn
        public String hamtaNamn()
            {
            return namn;
            }

    // returnerar adress
        public String hamtaAdress()
            {
            return adress;
            }  

        public void saljbil()
        {

                if (personbil==null)
                {   
                System.out.println("Du har ingen bil att sälja");
                }

                else
                {
                System.out.println("Tackar och bugar för bilen");
                personbil = null;
                }
        }

            public void kopBil (String bilmodell, int hamtaarsmodell,String hamtaregnr, String bilfarg)
            {

                System.out.println("tack för ditt bilköp");
                personbil = new Personbil(bilmodell, hamtaarsmodell, hamtaregnr,bilfarg);       


            }         
          public void infoBil()
          {
            if (personbil==null)
            System.out.println("Äger ingen bil för närvarande");
            else
            personbil.SkrivutInfo();
         }

            public void infoAgare()
            {
             System.out.println("förarinfo\nNamn" + namn +"Adress,"+adress);

            }


public static void main (String [] args)
        {

        Personbil bil1 = new Personbil("Saab",90, "CCC222", "röd");
        Personbil bil2 = new Personbil("Volvo",99, "ABC988", "svart");

        bilagare a = new bilagare ();

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Syntax Error

public void saljbil();
```

Remove ; from the method definition

Answer (score 2):

`public void saljbil();` remove the semi-colon

It should be:

```
 `public void saljbil()`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void saljbil();
```

Remove the semi-colon

```
public void saljbil()
```

Do the same for the `kopBil()` method.

Having a semi-colon at the end of a method signature disassociates the code block that follows it.

Answer (score 0):

Just some minor adjustments required:

```
public void saljbil();
      remove ; here  ^

public void kopBil (String bilmodell, etc.);
                            remove ; here  ^
```

BTW, `getAll()` is not defined in class Personbil:

```
personbil.getAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is probably what you want, even though you should fix all your errors that have been suggested beforehand;

bilagare a = new bilagare (*string*, *string*, bil1);
    bilagare a = new bilagare (*string*, *string*, bil2);
```